# javascript Adding timer to web page. using java script function on button click i am trying to add timer to my web page

Tags: javascript

while i am trying to run timer on my web page on button click page loaded and the timer shown for while and when page load complete timer dis appear to the page
code is following.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to   

function StartTimer() {
  debugger;

  // var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 10, 2022").getTime();
  var countDownDate = new Date().getTime()+10000;
  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + " " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    debugger;
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

StartTimer();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I made a snippet and added the function call. Please create a [mre] and explain what exactly the issue is. Also make sure to check the browser console for errors.

Comment: It runs ok in the demo here. Please ensure the code you've provided actually demonstrates the issue you're trying to describe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sir I actually want this above function to be called upon the button click. but when I am clicking on the button the page post back , the timer once shown  then disappear. Please suggest needful

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to calculate the current time in your `setInterval()` callback each time. The callback will be called repeatedly in one second intervals. You could simply decrease the initially calculated  number of seconds (`diff`) and use that as the source of "remaining time":

```js
const p=document.getElementById("demo");

function StartTimer(endTime) {
  const units=[[86400,3600,60,1],"days,hours,minutes,seconds".split(",")];
  // remaining time in seconds:
  var diff = Math.round((endTime - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
  // Update the count-down once every second (=1000ms):
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    const d=[]; // array with [days,hours,minutes,sconds] of remaining time
    units[0].reduce((a,c)=>(d.push(~~(a/c)),a%c),diff); // calculate d here!
    p.textContent=d.map((c,i)=>`${c} ${units[1][i]}`)
                   .join(", ")+" to go.";
    if (diff--<1) {
      clearInterval(x);
      p.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

const endTime=new Date(new Date().getTime()+10000); // 10 seconds into the future
console.log("end time:",endTime)
StartTimer(endTime);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```